# How to solve "OperationalError: database is locked" with simultaneous /admin and management command sessions?

Tags: python, django, sqlite

I'm using django with sqlite for a web application which executes a long-running management command to update the database (`./manage.sh download_company_data`). However, while it's running, I'm unable to create a new user in the Django admin interface. I've already increased the timeout option for the database to 20000:

```
DATABASES = {                                                                              
    'default': {                                                                           
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',                                            
        'NAME': BASE_DIR / 'db.sqlite3',                                                   
        'OPTIONS': { 'timeout': 20000 },                                                   
    }                                                                                      
}
```

The operational errors are immediate, though, ignoring the configured timeout. They happen after clicking on the save button when trying to add a user to the database.

I'm simultaneous running the database update process and a `runserver` process for the admin site. The individual updates are simple and fast, don't access the `User` table and I have also tried to disconnect from the database and sleep to give room for the server process:

```
    for line in c:                                                                
        line = preprocess(line, prefix)                                           
        search = { unique: line[unique] }
        for i in range(10):                                                       
            try:                                                                  
                Model.objects.update_or_create(**search, defaults=line)           
                break                                                             
            except OperationalError as e:                                         
                info('Operational error. Delayed retry...')                       
                sleep(0.02)                                                       
        connections.close_all()                                                   
        sleep(1)
```

I don't understand why the admin site is repeatedly giving operational errors mentioning the database is locked, even when there's only 1 connection to the sqlite file most of the time.

Is there any way to solve this without switching sqlite to another database backend ?

Comment: That's the entire problem with sqlite and why it is typically only used only to test software or for programs where a single run manipulates the database or as a read-only database: it does not work with concurrent writing, and therefore is not really fit for a webserver.

Comment: In certain situations, django or sqlite are able to wait for the concurrent transaction to finish, for example, by simply busy-waiting and retrying. This is a case where such approach would, since each individual transaction is really small. I thought configuring the timeout would do this. Is this possible ?

Answer (score 0):

try using transaction.atomic()

```
from django.db import transaction

# Inside your management command
@transaction.atomic(isolation=transaction.ISOLATION_READ_UNCOMMITTED)
def your_long_running_task():
    # Your code here
```

Comment: It didn't work, the admin site just gets stuck waiting for the long-term transaction to finish.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).